# ImportError: cannot import name 'sample' from 'random'

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am getting following error
ImportError: cannot import name 'sample' from 'random'

The usual solution is to rename the file name but I do not have any filename as sample , random or random_sample in my codebase. To further work on it, I created a virtual env name "new_venv" and I still have the same error.

Investing further more, I find the same path is been referred with venv or without venv

ImportError: cannot import name 'sample' from 'random' (/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/random.py)

Other thing I tried

- Set the correct version of python interpreter env in VSCode but  no luck.
- Tried running  /Users/user/folder_name/new_env/bin/python myscript.py

please note, I am running the script in terminal (inside vscode)

Any clue , what might be missing here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 2, in <module>
    from random import random, choice, sample
ImportError: cannot import name 'sample' from 'random' (/Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/random.py)
```

Line 2 is

```
from random import sample
```

Comment: My guess would be that your library file has been damaged.  If you look at that file, do you see "def sample"?

Comment: can you provide the full text of the traceback?

Comment: Tim, I do see def sample

Comment: On my system, `def sample` is actually a class function, so that wouldn't be the same thing.  The actual imported item is `sample = _inst.sample`

Comment: in my script there is no def sample , in random.py I do see def sample

Comment: Good point.  At the bottom, do you see `sample = _inst.sample`?

Comment: @TimRoberts no... but it randintsample = _inst.sample

Comment: is it advisable if I change randintsample to sample ?

Comment: you're not using standard python3.8.2 -- there is no "randintsample" in the source code.

Comment: Yes, it looks like someone accidentally edited that file.  You should have `randint`, `choice`, `randrange`, and `sample` in 4 consecutive lines.

Comment: Compare with https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/random.py